# Eclipse (3.5) how to compare files horizontally?

Tags: eclipse, compare, filecompare, file-comparison

Normally Eclipse 'File Compare' compares files in vertical panels like:

[image: Compare using Vertical Panel]

Is there a way I can compare them horizontally like:

[Compare using Horizontal Panel http://www.sqlservertool.com/images/ad_hex_diff_small.gif](http://www.sqlservertool.com/images/ad_hex_diff_small.gif)

Its too tiring to scroll everytime to see what was changed!!

Thx

Comment: Scrolling up/down or left/right? If L/R, get a wider monitor (see the joel test item #9: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html)

Comment: I also found the "changing layout from horizontal to vertical" function is necessary but absent. However, in order to diff line-to-line, viewing horizontally is more convenient. Maybe what you need is an additional panel marking the current comparing lines vertically, besides the horizontal one, like what we see in Beyond Compare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the code of [`org.eclipse.comparator.internal.CompareEditor`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/compare/internal/CompareEditor.java.htm) (which is the name of the class of the editor illustrated in your question), I do not see any indication of a different "orientation" (horizontal layout vs. vertical layout)

So, no. I do not think the current implementation allows you to compare files with a different layout.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Robert was referring to Select Next/Previous Change/Difference buttons (see section Toolbar in [Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-25.htm)).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid VonC is right that the current implementation doesn't support changing the layout, but there is a [bug open](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=128327) for it so you can either provide a patch or ping guys from Eclipse Workspace Team (including me :) and ask them to fix it for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is scrolling, use the toolbar buttons to navigate between changes.

Comment: Didn't completely understood what you mean by toolbar buttons...if the source content width is more than 70 (I am using a 21" monitor) I still have to scroll using the mouse...e.g. in BeycondCompare I can change the view to horizontal/vertical I am looking something like that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to overcome your problem is to `Maximize` editor window during file compare, and then `Restore` it after compares are done.  I wish Eclipse did it by default.

As to the question of orientation.  I think it's more readable when you compare revisions side-by-side. That's probably why Eclipse authors did not give us an option of horizontal layout.  What they could have given us were a **line** diff at the current cursor position.